# Access facebook api to get restaurants

Tags: javascript, facebook, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I am accessing the Facebook Graph JS API, in order to display some of the user's favorite movies, music and so on. Now I want to access all the restaurants a user has liked. I didn't find anything in the API-doc, that this is supported. So I think about parsing all the likes of a user like this:

```
   FB.api('/me/' + 'likes' + '?access_token+' + accessToken,
       function(response){
          for(var k=0; k<response.data.length; k++){
             // Do some stuff with the data
          }
    });
```

Is this the only solution or do you know something else?

How would you code this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   FB.api('/me/likes?limit=5000&access_token=' + accessToken,
       function(response){
          var restaurants = [];
          for(var k=0; k<response.data.length; k++){
             // Do some stuff with the data
             if(response.data[k].category=="Food/beverages")
                 restaurants.push(response.data[k]);
          }

    });
```